# Can someone help me get my firebase static site running?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, directory, console-application, azure-static-website-hosting

I followed all the prompts and instruction and everything and it brings me here.

{
"hosting": {
"public": "public",
"ignore": [
"firebase.json",
"**/.*",
"**/node_modules/**"
]
}
}

I'm new to this and not sure what I'm doing wrong. thanks

I followed on screen prompts for launching firebase static website.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, can you eloborate what the issue is and whats happening? is the deployment successful, are you getting an error?

Comment: Hello mohamed I dont know if you saw my linked image. It's bringing me to welcome screen that says Welcome
Firebase Hosting Setup Complete
You're seeing this because you've successfully setup Firebase Hosting. Now it's time to go build something extraordinary!

OPEN HOSTING DOCUMENTATION
Firebase SDK loaded with auth, database, firestore, functions, messaging, storage, analytics, remoteConfig, performance    I created the directory through console and firebase init and then firebase deploy. however. no website displaying. please see attached picture.

Comment: attached link   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VPKU.png

Comment: Hi again, this issue is most common, and your deployment is successful let me help you in the answer section with details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as i said earlier the development is successful but its not reading your .HTML file it instead is reading a default HTML file generated by firebase.

first create a source folder eg- dist keep your files inside this folder and open your command prompt, do a firebase init, I know you did this already still do it again and see the file path, in your command prompt, save the dist folder in that exact location.
then if it asks to replace the original fille or overwrite give no and deploy it with firebase init

This might seem triky just do it and let me know here ill help you further.

[image]

Inthis picture, the the dist folder should be inside cdrive-users-a850213-dist

Comment: Hello, I tried adding specifically eg- dist into my directory path. then ran firebase init and deploy as usual. same thing. here is a picture. Not sure if this is wht you meant. My website files are inside of that eg- dist folder

Comment: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJudf.png)

Comment: its fine mate, i have been there couple of years ago, so wait let me tell you a easy way to find it, so you have your HTML file right? that's not deployment instead a default HTML page created by firebase is deployed, so listen here carefully, search in your PC for index.html files and open each one of them one by one, by right click and open the htmll files with chrome or edge, you will definitely find a HTML file, if you open it it will display the error you are seeing, I mean deployment successful in firerbase etc etc. after finding that

Comment: after finding that note the exact path and then put your files there, there should be your files don't keep dist folder the contents inside your dist folder and HTML file should be there too. let me know if there is any improvement, don't wry I got ur back you are going to get it deployed for sure.

Comment: Hey mohamed it is working now. I do appreciate all your help. I was up all night last night trying to figure that out.